# i cant remove a path in my sending email form [winform]

Tags: c#, winforms

my email format looks like this or my design:
[image: my email format looks like this or my design]
   my cross is not working even if i press the cross and send an email it     still sends an attached file

still i tried everything Eg i used if else conditions and if you can help me fix this it would mean a lot and thanks in advance for looking at my question

```
    String path = "";
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
           //to add attached file
            path = openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory + openFileDialog1.FileName;
            label10.Text = path;
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = path;

        }
    }

    private void label12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //cross to remove the attached file
        String path = "";
        label10.Text = "'Attached File Location'";
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = path;

    }
    private void label11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (path != "")
            {
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

                message.From = new MailAddress(textBox2.Text);
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress(textBox3.Text));
                message.Subject = textBox1.Text;
                message.Body = richTextBox1.Text;
                //attached path sendds here
                message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(path));
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.Host = "smtp." + textBox5.Text.ToLower() + ".com";
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(textBox2.Text, textBox4.Text);
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.Send(message);
                MessageBox.Show("Success, Email has been successfully sent to "+textBox3.Text);


            }
            else if(path == "")
            {
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

                message.From = new MailAddress(textBox2.Text);
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress(textBox3.Text));
                message.Subject = textBox1.Text;
                message.Body = richTextBox1.Text;
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.Host = "smtp." + textBox5.Text.ToLower() + ".com";
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(textBox2.Text, textBox4.Text);
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.Send(message);
                MessageBox.Show("Success, Email has been successfully sent to " +textBox3.Text);

            }
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. What is actually your problem? the condition `if (path != "")` doesn't work and even when the path is empty enter in the block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a local path variable

```
private void label12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    //cross to remove the attached file
    String path = "";
```

use global path instead

```
private void label12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    //cross to remove the attached file
    path = "";
```